# AxisFault: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, axis, handshake, blackboard

I'm connecting to a local instance of my Blackboard virtual machine with a Java program, but I'm receiving an Axis exception when the program attempts to send information to the localhost.

#### Error Log:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:542)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:435)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at edu.ku.it.si.bbcontextws.generated.ContextWSStub.initialize(ContextWSStub.java:2180)
at edu.ku.it.si.blackboardduedates.BlackboardDueDatesServiceImpl.getBlackboardDueDatesForUser(BlackboardDueDatesServiceImpl.java:53)
at edu.ku.it.si.blackboardduedates.BlackboardDueDatesApp.main(BlackboardDueDatesApp.java:34)
   
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:94)
... 19 more


Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:462)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
... 25 more
```

Comment: It turns out while I have Java 1.8 installed on my machine, my IDE was using Java 1.6 and that's what was messing everything up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?